# How many possible combination that sums up to a number from a mix of positive and negative 1?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

Suppose:

A monkey randomly writes down a series of +1 and -1.

The series contains $n$ elements. For example, if $n=2$, then the series can either be
$\left \{ 1, 1 \right \}$ or $\left \{ -1, 1 \right \}$ or $\left \{ 1, -1 \right \}$ or $\left \{ -1, -1 \right \}$.

A human then sums up the elements contain in the series. For example, for $n=2$, the sum could either be 2 or 0 or -2.

Notice that there 2 series combination that results to a sum of 0. $\left \{ -1, 1 \right \}$ and $\left \{ 1, -1 \right \}$

**I wish to find a formula that determines: for a given n, how many series combination that results to a sum of $x$?**

To explain, here are some examples:

1. If $n=2$ and $x=0$, then there are only 2 combinations (above example)
2. If $n=4$ and $x=-2$, then there are only 4 combinations
3. If $n=4$ and$x=4$, then there are only 1 combination

**Non-critical notes:**

1. This question was asked to me by my sister and I have spent a long time trying to figure it out, but obviously I need help. Coming from engineering background, I have never touch combinatorics and counting since pretty much high school. I think the question is interesting because the set contains -1, which "cancels" out the +1, so traditional methods such as ["stars & bars"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462099/number-of-possible-combinations-of-x-numbers-that-sum-to-y) does not work.
2. For simplicity, $n$ is always even number. Additionally, because +1 and -1 are odd numbers, hence $x$ is also always an even number.
3. For the case $n=2$, it is like drawing a 2 x 2 table where the row and column headers are 1 and -1, while the each entries are the sum of the respective row and col header. In this table, the entries are the same value in each top-left-to-buttom-right diagonals. For the case $n=3$, it is like drawing a 2 x 2 x 2 cube where the headers are 1 and -1, and again, similarly, in 1 of the diagonal direction, each entries have the same value in that diagonal. So this problem boils down to how many entry cells that a particular diagonal crosses.

Comment: Given $n$ and the desired sum you can compute the number of $+1$s.  Now find the number of ways to pick that many positions out of $n$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: what about the $-1$s subtracting the sum? Am I missing something?

Comment: There are $a\ +1s$ and $b -1s$.  You have $a+b=n, a-b=sum$  Two equations in two unknowns.